# Input to one ansible playbook need to be passed to another playbook

Tags: variables, ansible

Kindly refer the below sample, where I have 2 different playbooks executed with "import_playbook". Here I will get the password as input using vars_prompt in first playbook, I need to use the same password variable in the second playbook. Kindly suggest the best possible options, {NOTE: I cannot merge both plays into single play as they are executed in different hosts}
PLAY 1:

```
---
- name: Install PCS cluster
  hosts: cluster_nodes
  vars_prompt:
    - name: password
      prompt: Enter the HACLUSTER user password
  tasks:
    - name: Configure password for hacluster user
      user:
        name: hacluster
        password: "{{ password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
```

PLay 2:

```
- name: Configuring Cluster
  hosts: 172.17.254.3
  vars:
    cluster_nodes:
      - node1.domain.com
      - node2.domain.com
  tasks:
    - name: Authenticate the cluster nodes
      shell: "pcs host auth -u hacluster -p {{ password }}  {{ ha_nodes | join(' ') }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a dummy_host and put your variable in it, like this:

```
- name: vartest1
  hosts: cluster_nodes
  vars_prompt:
    - name: pass
      prompt: Enter the HACLUSTER user password
  tasks:

    - name: hashpassword
      set_fact:
        password: "{{ pass | password_hash('sha512') }}"

    - debug: msg="{{password}}"

    - name: Register dummy host with variable
      add_host:
        name: "DUMMY_HOST"
        PLAYVAR1: "{{ password }}"      


- name: vartest2
  hosts: 172.17.254.3

  tasks:
    - name: Echo the output 
      set_fact:
        password: "{{ hostvars['DUMMY_HOST']['PLAYVAR1'] }}"

    - debug: msg="{{password}}"
```

You could try if node1.domain.com is one of your server in group cluster_nodes

```
- name: vartest2
  hosts: groupe2

  tasks:
    - name: trap password
      set_fact:
        password: "{{ hostvars['node1.domain.com']['password'] }}"

    - debug: msg="{{password}}"
```

i prefer the first solution, because  with the second solution, if the server is offline you dont have access to hostvars